# Bootstrap Multiple - set selected values from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use angularjs and bootstrap in my application.  I am not sure how to set the selected value from server.

Below is my html code.

```
    <div class="col-md-9">
       <label>Select Users</label> 
       <select class="select-full" id="multipleUsers" 
           placeholder="Choose Multiple Users" tabindex="2" 
           multiple="multiple" ng-model="groupForm.users">
       </select>
    </div>
```

In js, I populate the dropdown values as follows when page loads,

```
var url = "/dropdown/getAllUsers";
var allUsers = new Array();
$http({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 200000
}).success(function (data1, status) {
    $scope.usersList = data1;
    $.each(data1, function (i) {
        allUsers.push({
            label: data1[i].name,
            value: data1[i].id
        });
    });

    $("#multipleUsers").multiselect('dataprovider', allUsers);
    $(".btn-group").hide();
}).error(function (data1, status) {
});
```

After selecting the values, i get the selected values as follows.

groupForm.users in js gives me all the selected users id in a comma separated value.

But I am not sure how to load the previously selected values from the server on edit.

On edit, the value should be loaded from the server as follows.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select . Mixing dom manipulation and angular is not the best way.

Comment: Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AngularJS, you can use [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). They are bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the [AngularUI Team](http://angular-ui.github.io/).

In general you can't do DOM Manipulation like your jQuery code does. A solution in your angular app can be [UI Select](http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

> In Angular, DOM manipulation is done inside directives. NOT
>   controllers.
>   http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/